# Guidance on Cryptocurrency questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Do we have any guidance on how to disposition cryptocurrency oriented questions? I have been seeing more of these lately. For instance, I ran across this other user's question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939143/how-to-set-the-price-of-a-tokenid-in-erc1155 today and it seems off topic.

[image]

The [ethereum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethereum) and [ether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ether) tags currently do provide some guidance, but its not 100% cut and dry (as usual).

For the sort of guidance I'm looking for is something like with [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel). Questions about Microsoft Excel are on topic for extensions, VBA, formulas, file format handling questions. Questions about using Excel as a typical user are off topic.

Comment: Usually, the litmus test is: is it about programming? Now I can't see the linked question (<10k rep pleb), so I can't provide commentary on that question. That said, we have (too) many cryptocurrency sister sites that may cover the other aspects: [Where can I ask cryptocurrency or blockchain questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363122/241919)

Comment: @AndrewT. updated with screen shot. its pretty vague if it is a programming question. it seems to be more about the ERC1155 than a specific implementation. hence the grey area.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking here/looking for. There's nothing special about cryptocurrency questions from Stack Overflow's point of view. Cryptocurrency questions get evaluated with respect to being on/off-topic on SO *just like any other question*.

Answer (score 7):

The questions posed in the screenshot appear to fall under the "too broad" (OK, it's technically "Needs Focus" these days) off-topic category.

First, that post is asking three questions, and SO questions should focus on one ask, not multiple. It also asks two additional follow-up questions in the last paragraph that are opinion-based, for a grand total of 5 different questions in one post. If the OP receives 5 different answers there and each answer only addressed one of the five questions (but did so correctly/completely), which one should they accept, and do you think that'd be fair to the rest?

Each of these questions also seem quite broad in scope & effort to fully answer, and dependent on details we don't have access to. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service... so asking how to implement an entire process is probably not gonna go over well here.

If someone has made an attempt at one or all of these things and encountered an actual blocking problem, they should ask about *that specific problem*, instead. Considering that question is about the Ethereum blockchain platform, I would consider asking it on Ethereum.SE instead of Stack Overflow. They even have a [FAQ list on their Meta](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/faq-frequently-asked-questions-and-reference-answers) about some commonly-asked questions that might be of some help.

Comment: although I agree with the sentiment of this post, thats not the ask - my ask is targeted at crypto questions in general.

Comment: @DanielA.White Then your question is too broad, beyond "they have to meet the criteria already covered in the help center". It'd be like asking "how do we handle OOP questions?"

Comment: Yes; I would also argue those questions likely would be considered "too broad" even on a site focused on NFT.  One of the reasons I believe is that, it's asking three different questions, instead of being singular focused.